# Need to query a column when conditions match in array header and data inside array

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Attaching a spreadsheet so that its easier explained that way:)

[SHEET HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N97mPWvjZmCPIBppLKjwGeKRho2-fsU2XDPv9iXP4J4/edit#gid=0)

I need to query a column of data when date matches with headers of an array & at the same time only the values 1 in that specific column of that array.

Very much thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a google spreadsheet see if this works:

```
=filter(B2:B12, filter(C2:N12, C1:N1=today())=1)
```

EDIT: if you want to be able to select a date (e.g. in cell C26) try

```
=filter(B2:B12, filter(C2:N12, C1:N1=C26)=1)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can we do this using Query function?!

Comment: Query is not the best option here. If wanted you can replace the outer filter with query... =query({B2:B12, filter(C2:N12, C1:N1=today())}, "select Col1 where Col2=1")